# Error when trying to install Python packages in PyCharm

Tags: python, package

I am trying to download a package, but each time, it gives me the following error -

```
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
ERROR: Malformed value in machine file variable 'python': Expecting eof got id.
```

I thought it was maybe an issue with the package itself (I don't know coding very well), but even if I try another package, it gives me the same error.

To give a bit more context, I hadn't used PyCharm in a while, but installing packages before was perfectly fine, so don't know what has changed. I expected the package to just download, I tried it in terminal and through the packages tab. I made sure to update pip to its latest version but nothing helps.

Comment: _I tried it in terminal_ Show us the exact command.